# I am trying to deploy django app on heroku but i seeing that error message

Tags: application-error

[My django app is successfully deployed but when I open the app url then this type of error message is showing please help me click below link to view error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXMB8.png)

[these are heroku view logs please tell me how this error will fix click on this link to see heroku view logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNkFr.png)

Comment: Seems like an error in your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.